# How to run single-node, multi-device data-parallel training with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Keras used to feature a `multi_gpu_model` that made it very easy to do data-parallel training on a single node with multiple GPUs. I see that this function will unfortunately be deprecated - [its doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model) saying that *"Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2020-04-01. Instructions for updating: Use tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy instead."*

This warning points to the [`tf.distributed.MirroredStrategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy) page which shows something much more verbose that what Keras users are used to and with zero mention to keras.

Hence the question: **What is the compact and intuitive way to do single-node, multi-device data-parallel training with Keras, if any?**

I'm looking for something as simple as `multi_gpu_model` was, or as intuitive as [gluon's multi-device SGD is](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter07_distributed-learning/multiple-gpus-gluon.html)